# Find orthogonal basis for 3x3 Symmetric Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonality

> Given a 3x3 symmetric matrix $A$ =\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & -1 \\ -1 & 1  & 1 \\ -1 &1&  1
> \end{pmatrix}
>   Find the orthogonal basis corresponding to the above matrix $A$

The eigen values for the above are coming out to be repeated i.e. 0 , 0 , 3
So for the symmetric matrix $A$=$PD$$P^{T}$ where $P$ is the eigen vectors corresponding to eigen values in $D$ and from $P$ matrix we get the orthonormal basis.  But here the eigen vectors corresponding to the eigen value 0 would not be unique so the matrix $P$ formed will have linearly dependent columns.

Can the above approach be used if the eigen values are repeated and eigen vectors are not distinct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the matrix $P$ will *not* have linearly dependent columns. If you compute the eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue $0$; you will see that they are the linear combinations of $(1,1,0)$ and $(1,0,1)$. Besides, $(-1,1,1)$ is an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $3$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: for eigen value 0 if i get eigen vector as (1,1,0) should it be the same for other column as 0 is repeated eigen value or another combination of eigen vector corresponding to it e.g. (1,0,1) to be taken?

Comment: No, it *cannot* be the same, since you want to get an invertible matrix.

Comment: Ok got it thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are in fact free to choose the null space $P$ columns as $0$ if you want to if your only goal is to write:

$$A = PDP^T$$

You can even choose to omit them completely. Then you will get something called a compressed Singular Value Decomposition.

(But it would not work if that subspace had another eigenvalue than $0$.)

Now your only goal was *not* to write $A$ factored in this way but to *find an ON basis*. Then you will need to search for vectors spanning this null space anyways no matter if you choose to put them in $P$ or not.

Comment: Ok got it thanks